# How to connect to external oracle db from kubernetes?

Tags: oracle, kubernetes

I'm setting up a new server using kubernetes to run Spring boot microservice. How do i get Spring boot app connected to external oracle database? (Database ip is 170.27.10.10:1521)

Kube Master's IP: 170.16.163.10
Kube Node's IP: 170.16.163.11
Kube Node can connect to server db.

I create deployment by command:

```
kubectl run db-deployment --image 170.16.163.30:5000/mcrdb:0.0.4 --replicas=2 --port=8083
kubectl expose deployment db-deployment --type=LoadBalancer --port=8083 --target-port=8083
```

And create service:

```
kind: "Service"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "dbdev"
spec:
  ports:
    -
      name: "oracle-db"
      protocol: "TCP"
      port: 1521
      targetPort: 1521 
      nodePort: 0


kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: dbdev
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 170.27.10.10
   ports:
     - port: 1521
```

And config db in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@170.27.10.10:1521/vservice
spring.datasource.username=dev_user
spring.datasource.password=dev_pass
```

Microservice can not started with error connect to oracle db.

Comment: Is this database reachable from within the cluster network? It looks like all the ranges are local. Also, remember that within the cluster all addresses are reachable, but outside of it, you can try pinging it from within a pod to test communication before the headless service approach.

Answer (score 1):

can you try below changes

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dbdev
spec:
  ports:
    -
      name: oracle-db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1521
      targetPort: 1521 


kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: dbdev
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 170.27.10.10
   ports:
     - port: 1521

application.properties
------------------------
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbdev:1521/vservice
spring.datasource.username=dev_user
spring.datasource.password=dev_pass
```

Comment: Hi @Ekambaram, thank for you answer. I just config but it not worked.
docker logs -f <id>
-------------------------------
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]

Comment: can you ping 170.27.10.10 from inside the pod?

Comment: you should also be able to ping dbdev from inside the pod

Comment: can we use oracle db schema on each pod along with spring bot application

Comment: could you please tell me what is vservice in jdbc string ? Where have you declared this in your config ?